# http and https in API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to select prefix of API dynamically.

Meance it dynamically take prefix if it is http: or https:.

So how to i check dynamically to response that if it's from http or https. so is any

Help me

Comment: You can simply use `//` rather than `http://` or `https://` to create a link using the "current" protocol.

Comment: i already used but is not worked for me.  And i am downloading Image from my own api.

Comment: I'm unsure of what your question is exactly please can you clarify

Comment: Ok. I have one API list which have no prefix meance it starts from @"\\google.", In which some of it have http: as prefix and else have https: as prefix. so how i dynamically mention that which api give me response with http prefix and https prefix.

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you are after. Do you just want to check whether it starts with `http` or `https`? OR do you want know what should it start with? Also what does `meance` mean? I don't think this is even a word.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps..
Refer "Handling redirects" from link...
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse: